# How to prevent site showing wsod in Drupal 8 custom code while using guzzle try block?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8.5 CMS ,I am using guzzle to call web service .If there is any error i get white screen with error.
'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error'

My code is as follow:

`try {
$response = $this->httpClient->post($endPoint, [
'verify' => FALSE,
'body' => Json::encode($data),
'headers' => [
'Auth-Token' => $token,
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
],
])
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
watchdog_exception('message', $e->getMessage());
}`

if i add 'http_errors' => false as option in post request i don't get white screen. Is there any other way of implementation that i don't get white screen with error if try block fails. The desired  feature is if there is a error in calling web service the default page should reload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30957410/5334703

Comment: @mradcliffe The solution on  stackoverflow.com/a/30957410/5334703 is not working

Comment: Your comment doesn't really help. You may not be implementing guzzle or exception handling correctly in your code per guzzle documentation.

Comment: It  finally work! i was missing name space "use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;"